# "No item selector views found" for JournalItemSelectorCriterion

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui

It was supposed to be a simple task, following the dev tutorial to create a selection pop-up:  https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/selecting-entities-using-the-item-selector

I followed this text, replacing the criterion by a JournalItemSelectorCriterion.

```
RequestBackedPortletURLFactory requestBackedPortletURLFactory = RequestBackedPortletURLFactoryUtil.create( request );

List< ItemSelectorReturnType > itemSelectorReturnTypes = new ArrayList<>( );
itemSelectorReturnTypes.add( new UUIDItemSelectorReturnType( ) );

JournalItemSelectorCriterion itemSelectorCriterion = new JournalItemSelectorCriterion( );

itemSelectorCriterion.setDesiredItemSelectorReturnTypes( itemSelectorReturnTypes );

return itemSelector.getItemSelectorURL( requestBackedPortletURLFactory, selectedEventName, itemSelectorCriterion );
```

The OSGi components are in order, otherwise I would get a null pointer exception.

When clicked, the button does open the dialog as expected, but without any entry, just a big:

> Selection is not available.

There is only one message in the logs:

> No item selector views found for
>   com.liferay.journal.item.selector.criterion.JournalItemSelectorCriterion

```
$('#<portlet:namespace />selectJournal').on(
    'click',
    function(event) {
        var itemSelectorDialog = new A.LiferayItemSelectorDialog(
            {
                eventName: 'selectWcToSend',
                on: {
                    selectedItemChange: function(event) {
                        var selectedItem = event.newVal;

                        if (selectedItem) {
                            var itemValue = JSON.parse(
                            selectedItem.value
                        );
                        var wcUuid = itemValue.uuid;

                        $('#<portlet:namespace />uuid').val(wcUuid);
                    }
                }
                },
                title: '<liferay-ui:message key="select-web-content" />',
                url: "${journalSelectorUrl}"
            }
        );
        itemSelectorDialog.open();
    }
);
```

Any thoughts?

ps: using Liferay 7 GA5

ps2: same issue here: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/104166898

A bit odd: the code works when I change `itemSelectorReturnTypes.add( new UUIDItemSelectorReturnType() );` to `itemSelectorReturnTypes.add( new URLItemSelectorReturnType() );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much information out there about this, so I will leave here what I found:  this specific criterion does not support UUID as the return type.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.x/modules/apps/web-experience/journal/journal-item-selector-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/journal/item/selector/web/internal/JournalItemSelectorView.java

```
_supportedItemSelectorReturnTypes = Collections.unmodifiableList(
    ListUtil.fromArray(
        new ItemSelectorReturnType[] {
            new FileEntryItemSelectorReturnType(),
            new URLItemSelectorReturnType()
        }));
```